# How to properly sum array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a problem to get the sum of my array. I'm using Adwords script, which works like javascript. I can "print out" my array which shows the numbers i'm interested in. Like `[23369.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`. But when I'm adding them together using my for-loop the results produce `NaN` (Not-a-Number). I don't really know what to do.

```
var spend = [];

function main() {
  var campaignsIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns().get();
  var sum;

  while(campaignsIterator.hasNext()) {
    var campaigns = campaignsIterator.next();
    var stats = campaigns.getStatsFor("THIS_MONTH");
    var costPerAdG = stats.getCost();

    spend.push(costPerAdG);
  }

  for(var i in spend){
    sum += parseInt(spend[i]);
  }

  Logger.log(spend);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize `sum` with `0`, otherwise the value is `undefined`.

If you add a numerical value, you get `NaN` - if you add a string, then the result is `'undefined' + string`.

```
var sum = 0;
//      ^^^
```

```js
var a,
    b = 0;

a += 1;
b += 1;
console.log(a); // NaN
console.log(b); // 1
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

You could also define `sum` *and* actually sum your array in a single clean one-liner:

```
var sum = spend.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple function for getting the sum of an array

```
function sumarr(arr){
    return arr.reduce(add, 0);
}

arr=[23369.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

sumarr(arr)
```